# Find a method in GoDoc

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to Go and am just starting to get to the point where I need to be able to use GoDoc efficiently.

I work a lot with kubernetes and there are a TON of packages in the client-go module, thing. I want to find a particular method and read about it `informers.NewSharedInformerFactory`. Is there a good way to search for this method within the `client-go` module, thing?

I've been CTRL+Fing may way through the package index without much luck.

Something similar to Elixir's hex docs: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html

Or Scala/Java's docs: https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/index.html

Comment: Answer is the third result, and it doesn't necessarily handle the case of what are all of the functions with this name across the whole package.

Maybe I should just add some googlefu to restrict the search to that domain.

Comment: If you're using an editor that supports it, you can use the Go language server to go to definition/peek definition, etc. If your editor doesn't support language servers, there's go-guru.

Comment: @Breedly "what are all of the functions with this name across the whole package" there can be only one function with a given name in a package.

Comment: @Adrian so client-go is made of multiple packages. Would you call that a module?

Comment: It's a module if it uses Go modules. The most general term would be library I guess?

Comment: If the go package is installed, then doesn't `go doc informers.NewSharedInformerFactory` show you the information you need?

Comment: @aMike That's cool! I didn't know about that. However, it gave me documentation for the wrong package. github.com/docker/cli/kubernetes/client/informers

Comment: Interesting. I'm at the limit of what I know.  I usually use an app called Dash (look for alternates, like Zeal), so I don't type 'go doc' that often.  OK, how about: `https://godoc.org/?q=informers` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just so no one else recommends googling:

`site:godoc.org inurl:client-go SharedInformerFactory`

does alright. Search results don't provide rich context that makes it easy to pick the right one or learn more about the other results the popped up. Probably a symptom of client-go's sparse documentation. I guess I shouldn't expect more since many libraries/frameworks/languages I've searched also don't have search functionality.

[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/)

[Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html)

Can get better results using [sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=repo:%5Egithub%5C.com/kubernetes/client-go%24%20NewSharedInformerFactory&patternType=literal#1) and just read the comments.

Query: `repo:^github\.com/kubernetes/client-go$ NewSharedInformerFactory`

Comment: I used the search term `informers.NewSharedInformerFactory` which gave the result as the top hit.

Comment: Thanks @PaulHankin. I'm sorry my question started out so vague and Google is definitely _a_ solution, but if you use something like hexdocs you realize that it provides a lot of context specific search that really accelerates your ability to work with new libraries that Google does not provide. Thanks for working with me as I reformulate the question.